# Como remover uma View de um layout xml?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, view

por exemplo...
quero que ao inflar um layout com uma determinada classe, ela remova as views desnecessárias e utilize apenas as necessárias... Existe um método para remover views?

Comment: [ViewGroup.removeView(view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consigo enxergar duas maneiras de fazer isso. A primeira é que você pode esconder a view que deseja através do método `suaView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. Ela vai continuar lá, mas não estará visível. A segunda é que todo layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout e etc) herda de ViewGroup, e essa classe tem o método `[removeView(suaView)][1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode setar a visibilidade da view como GONE, esse parâmetro 'remove' o item da tela

```
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```